# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS not fully showing some git commands

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, git-branch

(new to linux terminal, comming from git bash)
Linux terminal isn't showing the git command response in some cases. Git branch for example. [git branch does not list branches (git branch -l doesen't work either), but there clearly is a branch since git status returns it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvAWK.png)

Any ideas on what could be the problem? Should I use different command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A  branch with no commits yet doesn't yet really exist, when you commit the first time that's the one you'll make. `git status` shows you as "on" that branch because that's the tip you'll commit to, `git branch` *doesn't* show you that branch because you can't do anything (else) with it yet.